# Prove every element of $G$ has finite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group such that the intersection of all its subgroups which are different from $\{e\}$, is a subgroup different from $\{e\}$. Prove that every element of  $G$  has finite order.

Assume that $a$ has infinite order in $G$. Then let $y\neq e$ belong to the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ different from $\{e\}$. Then $y=a^n$ and $y$ will also belong to subgroup generted by $a^2$ hence  $y=a^{2m}$ for some integers $m$. This contradicts that $a$ has infinte order.

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you find that $y=a^n=a^{2m}$?

Comment: $y$ will also belong to subgroup generted by $a^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express your idea differently:

If $G$ has an element $a$ of infinite order, then the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups is trivial.

Indeed, this is true for $\mathbb Z$, which is isomorphic to $\langle a \rangle$.

Therefore, if the intersection of all nontrivial subgroups is nontrivial, then $G$ cannot have an element of infinite order and so all elements must have finite order.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely true, but it is the idea  precise that $y$ is in the group generated by $a$ so $y=a^n$. $y$ is also in the group generated by $a^{2n}$ so $y={a^{2n}}^m=a^{2nm}$, so $a^{2nm-n}=1$ contradiction

Comment: because it is in the intersection of all subgroup of $G$ and the subgroup generated by $a^{2n}$ is a subgroup of $G$.